# Ember data FixtureAdapter hasmany - Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

again struggling with ember-data >.< , the bug here is on the FixtureAdapter, whenever i use a hasmany relationship, i get the errors `Error while loading route: TypeError {}`  `Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined"`

## Library versions

```
Ember: 1.1.3+pre.e0ffbf84
Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.3
Handlebars: 1.0.0 
jQuery: 1.9.1
```

## The code, also [here in a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oTIkigAV/3/edit)

### Uncomment the items: hasMany line in the Facture model to reproduce the bug..

Thanks for the help, it might be a bug, in which case i will post an issue on github.

```
// Setup
App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

// Models
// Facture

App.Facture = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr(),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date', { defaultValue: new Date() })
    // Comment this line out and it does display a title
    //,items: DS.hasMany('item', { embedded: true })
});

// - Items
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    desc: DS.attr(),
    qty: DS.attr("number", { defaultValue: 0 }),
    price: DS.attr("string", { defaultValue: 0 })
});

// FIXTURES

App.Facture.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Services Informatiques",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        items: [
          { id: 1, desc:'Keay', qty: 2, price: "45" },
          { id: 2, desc:'You kidding', qty: 5, price: "75" }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Intégration Web",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        items: [
          { id: 1, desc:'lkelzekekl', qty: 2, price: "250" },
          { id: 2, desc:'You', qty: 5, price: "200" }
        ]
    }
];

// Routes
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return this.store.find('facture');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `RESTAdapter` and `FixtureAdapter` doesn't have support for embedded associations by default. Just `ActiveModelAdapter`.

There is some workarounds, with the `FixtureAdapter` you can use your fixtures, without the embedded data:

```
App.Facture.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Services Informatiques",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        items: [1,2]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Intégration Web",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        items: [3,4]
    }
];

App.Item.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, desc:'Keay', qty: 2, price: "45" },
  { id: 2, desc:'You kidding', qty: 5, price: "75" },
  { id: 3, desc:'lkelzekekl', qty: 2, price: "250" },
  { id: 4, desc:'You', qty: 5, price: "200" }
]
```

This is a jsbin with this sample http://jsbin.com/oTIkigAV/9/edit

To use with `ActiveModelAdapter`, just provide the configuration:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;

// serializer for Facture model
App.FactureSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    items: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

Using { embedded: true } in hasMany('item') don't worked for me :(.

And your payload need to have the `type: embeddedModel` property. In your case `type: 'item'`. Like the following:

```
{
    factures: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Services Informatiques",
            createdAt: newDate(),
            items: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    desc: 'Keay',
                    qty: 2,
                    price: "45",
                    type: 'item'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    desc: 'Youkidding',
                    qty: 5,
                    price: "75",
                    type: 'item'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Intégration Web",
            createdAt: newDate(),
            items: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    desc: 'lkelzekekl',
                    qty: 2,
                    price: "250",
                    type: 'item'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    desc: 'You',
                    qty: 5,
                    price: "200",
                    type: 'item'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

And a jsbin with active model adapter http://jsbin.com/oTIkigAV/10/edit

Comment: Thanks for answering, it does fix the error, but: a) ember is getting a bit frustrating as a beginner, is this "type" attribute documented anywhere ? b) How do i access the facture's items in my template now, it doesn't seem to be working just using an {{#each}} block, do i have to do something with a controller/template ?? :/

Comment: Maybe you can do just like me :) What I did was the following: Reading, reading, reading everything about EmberJS and Ember-Data. Then a small test with EmberJS. Then a small Ember-Data test. One hint: don't start right away. One must-see video: https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs One must read tutorial: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/ (this one uses a own defined file-structure which I do not like, however a good read). Have a great Ember taste!

Comment: Thanks for the cheer up :) i read quite a lot and already saw this peepcode AND read the smashing mag article. For now, i switched to [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) which seems to be simpler and enough for my needs, documentation is sparse and quicly out of date with embe; even SO questions get old fast. Oh well, Bleeding Edge :)

Comment: @Wilhearts I updated the answer even your accepting :). Because if you put your {{items}} property in the template. New errors will come. Ember data sometimes lazy evaluate things, and throw new erros. So now I think that the answer is good. Please give a look